# I need a JavaScript that will automatically change one GIF image to another OnOpen, one time, after 45 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, video

I have been scouring the web for a JavaScript that will allow me to change one GIF image to another, once, after 45 seconds on an HTML page. I found scripts to pre-load images, roll over scripts, multiple image slide show type scripts, along with a few other scripts. None of them fit my specific need.

I am about to create a web page with embedded images and sound. I have an MP4 video that I need about 45 seconds of to convert to an animated GIF one time on page open. I also have an animated GIF of about 20 frames (in a loop), of about the last 45 seconds of the video.

Based on the ability to convert the 45 seconds of video to an animated GIF, this is what I need to happen. The video clip is of a wall with a fireplace. The camera then zooms into the fire burning in the fireplace. Since I am blending imaged of flames, I don’t see any reason to be concerned if the flames don’t match up in the time of the image switch.

Other than previously mentioned, I would like the switch to be as seamless as possible (without any pause or drop out). I figured that if I set the timer to about 35 or 40 seconds, I won’t risk that passably. The current animated GIF is a portion of the burning flames. I want the first portion to play once and the last portion to repeat indefinitely. This is the only way

I can’t think of any other way to allow the image to continue on indefinitely, without draining users system resources and an extremely long load time for any kind of video loop. If the 45 second GIF file will be too large of a file or impractical to achieve, I will need a script to switch from an MP4 to a GIF.

Any detailed Java Scripting or recommendations you can provide will be very helpful and appreciated.

Thank you.

Joe

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { $("#imgid").fadeIn();$("#vidid").fadeOut(); }, 45000)`

Answer (score 1):

```
  var arrayOfImages = ['1.png', '2.png']; //where do the images come from
  x = 0;
  window.setInterval(function(){
      $('#img').attr("src", arrayOfImages[x]); //change the image to 1 from the array with index x
      x++;
  }, 40000); //intervaltime
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your reply. I am still learning JavaScript coding. If you have the time can you please show the complete script to </script>, showing all for the head section and for body section.

Comment: @MagicMan1660 Well Joe I'd love to. The problem is you gave me a general problem and I gave you a general answer. To be more specific I need to see your current code, you might want to paste it to jsfiddle.net and post a link here.

Comment: Thank you again Thomas. I currently do not have a script available that will swap two images. I have a timed script that will redirect to a new web page. I just don't know how to modify a that script or if it would even work. Even if I have to come up with a script that that uses an MP4 and a GIF, I know that when you have an embedded video that you need to click on to start, you can embed an image place holder. I figured there must be a way that you can have a video start on page open, and when it stops it could switch to an animated gif.

Comment: @MagicMan1660 It can, but you want too much with too little knowledge I'm afraid. I suggest starting with the codeacademy's jQuery tutorial and after that it should take you less than an hour to make a basic page that does exactly what you want. https://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-bay3D/0/1?curriculum_id=50a3fad8c7a770b5fd0007a1